# Rewrite rule is causing a redirect to another host and port rather than showing the content at the current URL

Tags: redirects, url, mod-rewrite

I have a web application working on:
`next3.info:83`

I want to go there with `weburen.next3.nl` so I used this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =weburen.next3.nl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^83
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://next3.info:83/ [L]
```

It goes to `next3.info:83` so the redirect works

But I want to see:
`weburen.next3.nl` **not** `next3.info:83`

How can I make this work?

Comment: *But I want to see: weburen.next3.nl not next3.info:83* Are you referring to the address bar in the browser?? Otherwise, this is confusing to me.

Comment: Yest I am referring to the adressbar in the browser. There I like to see weburen.next3.nl

Comment: You can't do this without using mod_proxy. When you specify a protocol/different host in the substitution mod_rewrite will implicitly trigger an external redirect. Incidentally, you are only rewriting to the document root (despite capturing the pattern) - is that intentional? Do you need to check the SERVER_PORT? Will `weburen.next3.nl` answer on port `83` as well?